# Getting Null Pointer Exception when trying to run the login script in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have recorded the login page script in blazemeter and trying to run it in JMeter but it's throwing Null Pointer exception error. Also for another script I am getting 401 unauthorized error code even if I have added the username, password, base URL in authorization manager.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, JMeter is saying that it is a Null pointer exception, without seeing your JMeter logs it is very difficult to predict what causing the issue.

The second error, since it is KERBIOS authentication, you need to make some changes in krb5.conf file and JMeter system properties file as well.

I would suggest you to checkout this well written article about windows authentication in JMETER: [Windows Authentication with JMETER](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)